# Doesn't clears the label messages on changing the selection using calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

Below is my aspx code for text box and calendar control and text box which displays an error message if the selected from date and to date is not in the range,the problem is i am getting error message but on again changing the date by using date picker i am unable to clear the label message not a valid document

```
<tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; text-align:left; padding-left:10px;">From Date:</td>
                        <td style="width:200px; text-align:left;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtfromdate" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="Calender"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td style="width:100px; text-align:left; padding-left:10px;">To Date:</td>
                        <td style="width:200px; text-align:left;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="Calender"></asp:TextBox> </td>
                        <td style="width:250px;"></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: is it webform appplication

Comment: You can't do it without uploading the file again. Since you need server side validation. If you want you can do all this validation and change label text process in client side using javascript but it's whole another story that you need to search the web for.

Comment: Oh and I forgot you can do it with form reloading this way when calendar changes you reload the page and user needs to upload the file again

Comment: even the msg in not getting disappered on uploading a file again

Comment: how to do it it with form reloading this way when calendar changes you reload the page and user needs to upload the file again

Answer (score 0):

All right according to comments what you need is to reload the page when the calendar values change. For this you do this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfromdate" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="Calender" ontextchanged="ClndrFrom_TextChanged">
```

And in your code behind:

```
private void ClndrFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here you clear your label. Or if you already stored the file in server 
    //you can validate your file and change the label
}
```

You also need to do the same thing for the other calendar text box.

For the record I recommend using client side code in Javascript for such operations but, hope it helps :)

Comment: i am not getting textchanged event i am getting ontextchanged

Comment: you told that you will edit the answer but it is not edited

Comment: I did. Just changed that little part. The whole thing is the same

Comment: but it is not firing on clicking the calendar control

Comment: It shouldn't fire on click. It should fire on text changed as the name suggests. If it still doesn't see this: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436223/Asp-Net-textbox-TextChanged-event-is-not-firing